# How do I filter the visible properties inside of a property grid's collection editor (win forms)?

Tags: c#, propertygrid, collectioneditor

I have a property grid that points to an object to view its properties. I filter by doing the following:

```
            propertyGrid1.BrowsableAttributes = new System.ComponentModel.AttributeCollection(new Attribute[]
            {
                new CategoryAttribute("All")
            });
```

My object has a collection of Control objects. When I view **just** the object, all of the properties that don't have [Category("All")] are filtered out. So far so good. However when I go into the collections editor, that editor shows properties that are not marked with [Category("All")]. This is undesirable. How do I remedy this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i fear you will have to subclass the collectioneditor to do that ...

[this article](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2008/05/how-to-take-control-over-collection.html) describes how to access the propertygrid on the form of the collection editor (see the overide of `CreateCollectionForm` in the article)

instead of registering eventhandlers you can setup your restriction for browsable attributes there ...